# How can I install python-iso8601_0.1.4-2_all.deb on Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid)

Tags: python, unix, ubuntu, installation, dependencies

I am using Ubuntu 10.04, which supports Python up to version 2.6.5.
However, I need to install the package python-iso8601_0.1.4-2_all.deb, 
which depends on python (>= 2.6.6-7~).

I can not upgrade the distro, since I am using some other packages
which are not supported in 10.10+

Thank you!

/Nico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats likely to break far too many things. You are better of installing the ISO 8601 package as an egg from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601/ for example.

Answer (score 1):

Install `pip`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential 
sudo pip install --upgrade pip 
sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

and then install your package:

```
sudo pip install iso8601
```